# Not working attempt for login laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, authentication, login-attempts

[controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQXte.jpg)

[user class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWJmq.jpg)

[views login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEqtm.jpg)

[routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fanlN.jpg)

I don't know why the login page doesn't work, but the registration page is correct What exactly is the problem that that "if" doesn't work ??

When I send the email and password, only the first line works. Reaching the database does not allow me to extract the information.

Comment: What error message you are receiving on login page?

Comment: Either the page just keeps going and the posts go down without any authentication, or it just says that the email or password is incorrect if the database is also complete.

Comment: The attempt does not work at all

Comment: There are no errors with the code you provided, which means there is an error somewhere else in your application or environment. We don't have enough information to give you an answer, unless you can be more descriptive or provide any error messages.

Comment: I added more images of the code

Comment: Hmm You are not registering the user.

Comment: No, the problem is the login section